# Count instances of strings across multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a df with this make-up. I'm interested in counting strings in the columns that have numerical names i.e. ['1','2','3','4','5']

[image]

And would return a series something like:

```
string1 10
strinsag1 5
strins1 5
```

...

I've tried various methods of groupby, Counter, and stack but I haven't found a solution that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack the data and use `value_counts()`:

```
df[['1','2','3','4','5']].stack().value_counts()
```